# If Statement doesn’t recognize string

Tags: python-3.x, string, if-statement, variables

I was trying to see if A was “x” but the code I used did’t work, it seems like A wasn’t “x” even when I typed in x. can someone tell me what did I get wrong?

```
import sys
A=(sys.stdin.readline)
if A == “x”:
   ‘’’ Code here’’’
```

When I type in x the if statement still won’t go off

Comment: Your quotes look bad. `'` or `"` not `‘`

Answer (score 1):

Did you realize that `A`is a reference to the `readline` function in your sample code? This is because it will never be equal to the character "x".

Edit:
Also, if you want to compare input string, I think you should trim the input string.

```
import sys
A=(sys.stdin.readline())

if A.strip() == "x":
    # Code...
```